# SQL cursor works but db doesn't save changes

Tags: sql-server, cursor, replacewith

I have a table which has undesired characters(Ý) and I want to replace it with "I". Before I have tried that code for another column name and it worked perfect. But now while debuging I can see it fixes the rows but at the end db has no change...  This is my code below:

```
  DECLARE @CARI_NAME varchar(100)
  DECLARE CRS_FixCariNameCURSOR FOR
  SELECT CARI_NAME FROM TBLCASABIT

  OPEN CRS_CariIsimDuzelt

  FETCH NEXT FROM CRS_FixCariNameINTO @CARI_NAME 

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0

  BEGIN
  IF @CARI_NAME LIKE '%Ý%'
  UPDATE TBLCASABIT SET @CARI_NAME = REPLACE(@CARI_NAME ,'Ý','I')
  WHERE CURRENT OF CRS_FixCariName
  FETCH NEXT FROM CRS_FixCariNameINTO @CARI_NAME 
  END

  CLOSE CRS_FixCariName
  DEALLOCATE CRS_FixCariName
```

Comment: Are  you missing `commit` statement?

Comment: That must be the problem but I don't know how to fix that with commit statement. I need help for that @Kishor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with  `UPDATE TBLCASABIT SET @CARI_NAME = REPLACE(@CARI_NAME ,'Ý','I')`
you update the variable and not the column!

use:
`UPDATE TBLCASABIT SET CARI_NAME = REPLACE(@CARI_NAME ,'Ý','I')`
if the column you want to update is called CARI_NAME

But what's more - Why do you even use a cursor here?
Simple Update does the same work more efficient (correct me if i am wrong):

```
  UPDATE TBLCASABIT
  SET CARI_NAME = REPLACE(CARI_NAME ,'Ý','I')
  WHERE CARI_NAME LIKE '%Ý%'
```

Comment: Can we use simple update for multiple rows without cursor? Thanks for ur help btw.

Comment: The Update Statement above will fix the CARI_NAME in all rows, where the CARI_NAME contains Ý.
You should use UPDATE Statements like this instead of cursor. Avoid cursor where you can, since row-based operations are far more slower than set-based operations